# WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.0.0 - retrieve administration console pwd

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I would like to know if there is a wat to retrieve the administration console password of a `WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.0.0` in a Windows 10 instalation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Weblogic admin password in boot.properties is not one-way encrypted. There are a number of blogs and tools which show you how to retrieve it. For example, try my tool found at https://github.com/b0tting/wlsdecrypter.

Answer (score -1):

You can't retrieve a password but you can reset it on the command line.

See https://wls4mscratch.wordpress.com/2010/05/31/steps-to-reset-console-password-in-wls-9x-and-above/